# How to identify existing user login Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How to identify the id (from push) of existing user?
I created a node using push when a user is registered, but when the user try to login again, I don't know how to identify it directly because its a different key.

Is it wrong to use push instead of the authentication id as my node? Because I want to retrieve the data I kept in my db for that user.

```
  // [START auth_state_listener]
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {   //I WANT TO RETRIEVE DB DATA HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask: *Is it wrong to use push instead of the authentication id as my node?* The answer is almost certainly, yes.  The documentation for [FirebaseUser.getUid()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getUid()) states:

> Returns a string used to uniquely identify your user in your Firebase
>   project's user database. Use it when storing information in Firebase
>   Database or Storage, or even in your own backend

The completion of the code in your post would be something like:

```
    if (user != null) {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("users").child(user.getUid());

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
    }
```

Comment: oh I see, my bad then, i often read people write use push to create primary keys, without any further consideration i use it as my user id.

Comment: Think this is correct answer. Wouldn't you mark it as correct ?

Comment: @Goofy_Phie using a key generated by `push()` is a great approach for collections where the items don't have a natural key, for example: for blog posts or if you're tracking whenever the user signs in. But for items that have a natural key (such as the UID of a user), it is best to use those items as the key in the collection.